# How to access ng-model value in directive?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I created a directive for google map auto-complete. everything is working fine, but the problem is when I need to access the value of input and re-set it. it doesn't work. Here is code:

```
<div controller='mainCtr'>
    <span click='reset(destination)'>Reset</span>
    <div class='floatleft' style='width:30%;margin-right:40px;'> 
            <smart-Googlemaps locationgoogle='destination.From'></smart-Googlemaps>
            <label>From</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the directive:

```
angular.module('ecom').directive('smartGooglemaps', function() {
    return {
                    restrict:'E',
                    replace:false,
                    // transclude:true,
                    scope: {
                      locationgoogle: '='
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'components/directives/autocomplete/googlemap-search.html',
                    link: function($scope, elm, attrs){
                        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($(elm).find("#google_places_ac")[0], {});
                        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                            // $scope.location = place.geometry.location.lat() + ',' + place.geometry.location.lng();
                            // console.log(place);
                            $scope.locationgoogle = {};
                            $scope.locationgoogle.formatted_address = place.formatted_address;
                            $scope.locationgoogle.loglat = place.geometry.location;
                            $scope.locationgoogle.locationText = $scope.locationText;
                            $scope.$apply();
                        });
                    }
                }
})
```

Here is html for directive:

```
<input id="google_places_ac" placeholder="Please enter a location" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model='locationText'/>
```

The directive works fine, I create a isolated scope(locationgoogle) to pass the information I need to parent controller(mainCtr), now in the mainCtr I have a function calld reset(), after I click this,I need to clean up the input make it empty. How Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to access the value of the model in your directive from a parent controller is to put that on the isolate scope too and use the two-way binding flag `=` like you've done with the `locationgoogle` property. Try this:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bOboJXEhgfFMUbOVRjSl?p=preview)

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
    <smart-googlemaps location-text="locationText"></smart-googlemaps>
</body>
```

**js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  // need to define model in parent and pass to directive
  $scope.locationText = {
    value: ''
  };

  $scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.locationText.value = '';
  }

});

 app.directive('smartGooglemaps', function() {
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      replace:false,
      // transclude:true,
      scope: {
        locationgoogle: '=',
        locationText: '='
      },

      // ng-model="locationText.value"
      template: '<input id="google_places_ac" placeholder="Please enter a location" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="locationText.value"/>',

      link: function($scope, elm, attrs){

          // implement directive googlemaps logic, set text value etc.

          $scope.locationText.value = 'foo';

      }
  }
})
```